# Storing a file Using XMPPFramework CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, xmppframework

I Know that the XMPPFramework can save messages on the client side using the XMPPMessageArchive.xcdatamodeld. The data Model  has a "message" attribute with an undefined type as shown in the picture.  My Question is how does the model differentiate between a normal text message and file like a video, photo or voice.

[image: eenter image description here]